# Is there a platform for publishing a digital textbook and workbook?

Tags: publishing, ebook

I watched a presentation from some textbook publishers where they showed off some software. It basically looked like Adobe, opening their textbooks and workbooks as a PDF or image, but had a few important features needed for classrooms:

- Students could log in, remotely download the textbook, and access is off-line, but only inside this app.
- Students could fill in the blanks, answer questions, directly on the page, and submit it to their teachers.

I am in need of exactly this type of software for a textbook, but when I researched the tools that the publishers shared, these were in-house tools seemingly owned by the very publishers who presented the digital textbooks. Is there a service, Web platform, or software providing this functionality, allowing independent publishers to contribute textbooks?

Comment: In what way does googling "digital publishing platform" not help you?